# Laravel 5 View Property doesn't exist Error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, view

Here is the view i need to fulfill.
[image]

So that i need to full table data and in under to that other details need to be fill once user fill it. So here is the view for that index.blade.php

```
 <table class="table table-bordered">
          <thead>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Data</th>
          </thead>

          <tbody>

               <tr>
                <td>Date</td>
                <td>{{ $items->date_of_programe }}</td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
                <td>Time</td>
                <td>{{ $items->time }}</td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
                <td>Venue</td>
                <td>{{ $items->venue }}</td>
              </tr>

          </tbody>
         </table>
```

```
             <table class="table table-striped">
              <thead>

                <th>Trainee Programe ID</th>
                <th>Presenter Name</th>
                <th>Division</th>
                <th>Date</th>
              </thead>

              <tbody>
              @foreach($items as $item)

            <tr>

              <td>{{ $item->training_programe_id }}</td>
               <td>{{ $item->presenter_name }}</td>
                <td>{{ $item->division }}</td>
                 <td>{{ $item->date }}</td>

            </tr>
                @endforeach 

              </tbody>
      </table>
```

So here is the error i'm getting.
[image]

So this is my controller index function.

```
 public function index()
{
   $items = trainingprogramedetails::all();
    return view('programesession.index',compact('items'));
}
public function create()
    {
        return view('programesession.programes');
    }

public function store(Request $request)
    {
        trainingprogramedetails::create($request->all());
                return view('programesession.programes');
    }
```

Here is my create view.

```
<div class="jumbotron">
            <div class="form-group">
            <label>Date</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="date_of_programe" type="date" value="2011-08-19" id="example-date-input">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">

            <label>Time</label>
            <input type="text" name="time" type="time" class="form-control" value="">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">

            <label>Venue</label>
            <input type="text" name="venue" class="form-control" value="">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
            <label>Training Programe Id</label>
            <input type="text" name="training_programe_id" class="form-control" value="TR/PR/">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
            <label>Presenter Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="presenter_name" class="form-control" value="">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
            <label>Division</label>
            <input type="text" name="division" class="form-control" value="">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
            <label>Date</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="date" type="date" value="2011-08-19" id="example-date-input">
            </div>

             <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right">
```

So can anyone suggest me to solve this error?
Thank you.

Comment: Well the error message is pretty self-explanatory. Can you tell us the result of dd($items) in your controller?

Comment: `$items` will be collections with arrays so you can not access it without index, try `$items[0]->date_of_programe`

Comment: sir um new to the laravel can you please say me what is the  dd($items)

Comment: Are you new to google, too?

Comment: it gives  Collection {#250 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▶]
}

Comment: There you have it, look at @DivyankMunjapara 's comment

Comment: @Amarnasan Problem is if user add new entries table values need to be auto updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
<td>{{ $items->date_of_programe }}</td>
```

The `$items` is a  collection of arrays, so to access its properties try:

```
foreach($items as $item)
{
    echo $item['date_of_programe'];
}
```

or

```
$items[0]->date_of_programe
```

Comment: Sir $items[0]->date_of_programe.works,but if user add new values table data should add as new values.how can i modify this?

Comment: Use the `foreach()` way instead, it works for all the properties

Comment: it works but all the datas in the database will be printed out now.how can i fixed it?